# Buttons in upper left don't work

Tags: bug, top-bar, stackexchange.com

There are three buttons in the upper left corner of the SE entry page, and on most SE sites.  They are the list of all sites, recent notifications, and recent changes to reputation.

They don't work for me in the SE entry page.  They appear to point back to the page they are on instead of pointing where they should, based on the behavior observed on "Open in new tab".

They do work, as they always did, in the SO site.  I haven't tested any other sites.

Is this a system problem, or is it just my environment?

---

Edit, based on responses.

I tried on a different computer, and it works, OK.  I'm using http: not https: in both cases.

The difference could be versions of Internet Explorer.  The three buttons work with IE verion 11.
They don't work with IE V 8.

Thanks for the comments.

Comment: What's your OS and browser?

Comment: With "entry page", do you mean www.stackexchange.com? They work for me (using FireFox 27 on Windows 8).

Comment: Internet explorer 8 isn't [officially supported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need) (nor is IE 9 for that matter) so this is likely to be a low priority. I assume upgrading isn't possible?

Comment: My workaround will be to use the other computer, until I can get my main computer upgraded.  Thanks.

Comment: upgraded computer...problem went away.

Answer (score 4):

You're using HTTPS, which isn't fully supported yet. Try https://stackexchange.com/ instead of https://stackexchange.com/

Comment: Specifically, the problem is that the page is trying to establish an insecure WebSocket connection, and the resulting security error crashes the jQuery `ready` event handler. If you're using Firefox, a workaround is to set `network.websocket.allowInsecureFromHTTPS` to true in `about:config`. (Of course, allowing insecure WebSocket connections may somewhat defeat the point of using HTTPS in the first place.)

Comment: My problem is something different.  This problem may affect others.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Derp. That's probably on me. I'll look into fixing that up on Monday.

Comment: @AnnaLear: Have you looked into that yet? A minimal fix would be to wrap the call to `StackExchange.realtime.subscribeToTopBarNotifications()` in a try/catch block so that it doesn't crash the whole jQuery ready queue. Of course, it would be even better if you could also replace the `ws://qa.sockets.stackexchange.com` with the corresponding `wss:` URL when the page is loaded over HTTPS.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Whoops, forgot about that. Should be fixed now.