# Site switcher doesn't work when using stackexchange.com over https

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar, stack-exchange-button, ssl

The top-bar site-switcher doesn't work when we are using https://stackexchange.com/ but works when using https://stackexchange.com/.

Clicking the site-switcher over https instead refreshes the page. Using individual sites over https doesn't exhibit this problem.

This problem happens when using Firefox 28 on Ubuntu 14.04. It seems to work as expected on Chrome 34.

Comment: Sounds like it may be a setting in firefox. Perhaps this would be a good question for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: The page loads over `https://`; just the site-switcher doesn't work. Hence, it's a bug-report at MSE. Things should work out-of-the-box (I know ssl is not officially supported here, but we are still free to report bugs). However, if you think that this makes a good question for [su], feel free to post a new one there :)

Comment: @Raystafarian ^^ forgot to ping you in previous comment..

Comment: @Aditya Are you seeing any issues with javascript loading in Firefox? We're not doing anything different per-browser here, obviously, so since it works in Chrome it should certainly be working in FF as well.  Are any other aspects of the page, such as the real-time loading of example questions, broken in FF?

Comment: @AnnaLear Everything else looks to be okay... Just when I click the site-switcher from any page of stackexchange.com domain over `https://`, the page reloads. Oh, and the **Inbox** and **Achievements** don't function as well. Clicking them doesn't trigger a refresh, but changes the url to `https://stackexchange.com/#`. Link to my profile, meta and about on the top-bar work as expected. Let me know if you need any kind of logs. I would be happy to help.

Comment: @Aditya I'm out of the office till Wednesday, but I'm going to try to repro this next week. Thanks for the report!

Comment: @AnnaLear The bug seems to have been fixed during MSO/MSE Split... It can be marked as [meta-tag:status-completed] :-)

Comment: @Aditya It got fixed as part of fixing [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227084/buttons-in-upper-left-dont-work/227085#comment754108_227085) and is unrelated to the split, but either way... status-completed. :)

Comment: @AnnaLear I still have this problem on Chrome Version 37.0.2062.124 m (64-bit). `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://stackexchange.com/topbar/site-switcher?_=1411635691827. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://stackexchange.com' is therefore not allowed access. search?q=42:1`